# Can i have two buttons in the same form in an .aspx file to interact with the server?

Tags: asp.net, forms, button, .net-4.0

I have an .aspx page in which i have two buttons at separate places inside the same form which is set to runnat="server". I need to have onclick attribute on both the buttons to call a function in the code-behind. The first button is calling the code-behind function when clicked but the second isn't firing at all. I searched a lot to find that i can't have two buttons interacting with the server in the same form. so how to do this. I really need both the butttons to call different functions in the code-behind.
Please help as i am a new-bee in asp.net. i am using c# on .net 4.
Can i have something like below in the same form and have the event handlers for these two buttons in the code-behind.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

Comment: Where did you find this information?  You most certainly _can_ have two buttons in an ASP.NET form.  Are you using Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: I am using Web Forms. Can both the buttons call separate functions in the code-behind?

Comment: Absolutely.  In Web Forms, the primary method invoked by a button is its click handler.  By default, something like `Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`.  You can assign multiple buttons to the same handler method, or a different handler method for each button.  Then, from within those handler methods, you can call whatever business logic you like.  Can you edit your question to include the code that isn't working?  The button markup, the code-behind handlers, anything relevant.

Comment: Post your ASPX markup and your code! I presume C#/VB.net.. ?

Comment: @Vikram: The buttons you added to the question are perfectly fine (except for their vague names).  They would each call `Button1_Click` and `Button2_Click`, respectively.  There's currently no indication of why this wouldn't be working.

Comment: Actually i got the error. i have a textbox for which i have a requiredfield validator which is not letting the other button to call the code-behind function.

Comment: please tell me where you saw that you can't have more than one button, i'd like to have a talk with that author :D

Comment: i closed the tab but vl surely find out again and post the link..